# How to stop an action with a button in scilab

Tags: scilab

I want to have the possibility to stop a function launched by a button by pushing an other button. More precisely, I want to stop a while loop by changing a parameter :

```
stop=%F
while ... & stop<>%T
    ...
end
```

I tried to write a callback function that change a variable to stop the while :

```
function callback(handles)
    stop=%T
end
```

but the action isn't triggered before the end of the previous one.

I guess there must be something to do with some threads but i don't have this knowledge in scilab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions. The first one with a prioritary expression callback:

```
b = uicontrol("style","pushbutton","callback","stop=%t","callback_type",10);
stop = %f;
while ~stop
    sleep(1)
end
```

the second one with a prioritary function callback:

```
function fun()
    stop = %t;
    stop = resume(stop);
end

b = uicontrol("style","pushbutton","callback","fun","callback_type",12);
stop = %f;
while ~stop
    sleep(1)
end
```

In the second case you have to use `resume` to return the local variable `stop` in the main workspace. Making callback prioritary is a must to interrupt waiting loops.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you validate the answer ?